# How to concatenate graphs files from different virtuoso instances?

Tags: merge, rdf, virtuoso

I currently maintain different instances of virtuoso to manage different RDF source files. At times I need to merge 2 or more of these instances into one.

The procedure I follow is the dump all graphs in a RDF serialisation-format (ie. Turtle), which I then merge and subsequently load in the instance that needs to contain the merged graphs.

I there a possibility to merge different virtuoso instances without this serialisation step, for example by concatenating the different virtuoso.db files?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both instances are running on the same machine, or at least in the same network...
I would run them both at a time (providing different sparql-endpoints), loading the (sub-)graph of one into the other using the sparql 'service' construct for federated queries. This has also the advantage of using CONSTRUCT if for example the graphs are based on different ontologies and do not fit naturally.
Have fun trying this out.